# Concave and Convex mirrors - How am i able to see the image without capturing on the screen but through my eyes?

Tags: reflection, glass

When a Object’s light rays hits a Concave or Convex mirror, the image forms. How am i able to see this image? I Know we cant capture virtual images on screen and can capture real image and the light rays meet at a point behind or infront of the mirror. If it is begind the mirror how am i able to see it?But How do i see the image without a screen? Does the reflected light rays meet at my retina?

For Ex take this image,how am i able to see the van in that glass. Does the glass has some phenomena images?

[image]

Comment: Because the front of your eye is a lens, which creates a real image on the retina.

Comment: You see the virtual image just as you see the virtual image of a plane mirror. Do you know how that happens?

Comment: Yes the reflected rays falls in my eyes. But how does it apply here? If the same phenomena of reflected rays falling in my eyes do i think that the image is formed in that mirror, but actually its not?